# What are the values for $ \lim_{ n \to \infty } E[(\overline{X}_n)^2] $ and $ \lim_{ n \to \infty } V[(\overline{X}_n)^2] $?

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

We have $X_1,X_2,...$ following iid.

Let $\overline{X}_n=\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and suppose that $E[X^4_1]$ has a finite value.

What are the values for $\displaystyle \lim_{ n \to \infty } E[(\overline{X}_n)^2] $ and $\displaystyle \lim_{ n \to \infty } V[(\overline{X}_n)^2] $   ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}\{(\overline{X}_n)^2\}&=\mathbb{E}\left\{\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^2\right\}\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb{E}\{X_iX_j\}\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\{X_i^2\}+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1\\j\neq i}^n\mathbb{E}\{X_i\}\mathbb{E}\{X_j\}\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\{X_1^2\}+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1\\j\neq i}^n\mathbb{E}\{X_1\}\mathbb{E}\{X_1\}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}\{X_1^2\}+\frac{n(n-1)}{n^2}\mathbb{E}\{X_1\}^2\\
\end{align}$$
where the second line comes from multiplying two sums, the third line comes from separating the cases when the sum indices $(i,j)$ are equal -yielding the second moment- or different -yielding the product of independent variables-, and finally replacing by $X_1$ because the $X_i$ are iid. You can take the limit here, as the second and first moment are finite given that the fourth moment is finite.

You can decompose the variance with a similar procedure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if we define $E[X_1] = \theta$, does $\displaystyle \lim_{ n \to \infty } E[(\overline{X}_n)^2]$ converge to $\theta ^2$ ?

Comment: Exactly. The first term tends to 0 (constant over $n$) and in the second term, the factor involving $n$ tends to 1. Hope this made enough sense to tackle the Variance.

Comment: Thank you so much. In the same way I got the Variance converging to 0.